# Mysqli (oop) running on mysql server but not mariadb

Tags: php, mysqli, mariadb

I have an online application that is written using the oop style of mysqli (i.e. connection method of `new mysqli`) and it has been working fine to date via a hosting company with servers running mysql version 5.0.11

I'm now needing to change to a different hosting company but before terminating my services with my current provider I have transferred a duplicate of the application to the new company so that I can test everything.

Unfortunately, the application isn't working as no connection can be made to their servers which are running MariaDB version 10.2.9

I have the ability via cPanel to activate/deactivate PHP extensions. Could it be one of those that needs enabling in order to get my oop mysqli code to run (both servers are running PHP version 5.5.38)?

For info; I've attached a screenshot showing the current extensions that are enabled on my account with the new provider.

Many thanks,
Alex.

[PHP Extensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bq10F.png)

Comment: Are you receiving any php errors when trying to connect to the database?

Comment: Is this a firewall issue?  Do you have any other clues (from logs, for example) about "no connection can be made"?

Comment: Hi Igor & Rick. I'm not getting any php errors other than just the server error 500. Firewall doesn't appear to be a problem as it's all 'localhost' and other php pages that I have are working...just not the ones with database access.